# no such table: TableName (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM TableName

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room, sqliteopenhelper

I am trying to delete the table using room Database and then executing Select Query on my table.

The problem is that one time it's executing the query properly. But another time it's throwing the below exception

```
Fatal Exception: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: TableName (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM TableName
```

Below is the code to Delete Table

```
    @Query("DELETE FROM TableName")
    public void delete_table();
```

Select Query

```
    @Query("SELECT * FROM TableName")
    public LiveData<List<Table>> getAllValues();
```

Model class for that table

```
@Entity(tableName = "TableName")
public class Table {


    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "LID")
    private int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "LOC_NAME")
    private String loc_name;

    public Table(){

    }

    public Table(String loc_name) {
        this.loc_name = loc_name;
    }

  public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLoc_name() {
        return loc_name;
    }

    public void setLoc_name(String loc_name) {
        this.loc_name = loc_name;
    }
}
```

Room Database Class

```
@Database(entities = {Table.class}, version = 2)
public abstract class RoomDB extends RoomDatabase {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "db-name";

    
    public abstract DataBaseDao getDatabaseDao();
    private static RoomDB instance;


    public static DataBaseDao getInstance(Context context){
        if (instance == null){
            synchronized (GoBumprRoomDB.class){
                if (instance==null){
                    instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context, RoomDB.class, DATABASE_NAME).fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

}
```

DAO class

```
@Dao
public interface DataBaseDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM TableName")
    public LiveData<List<Table>> getAllValues();

    @Query("DELETE FROM TableName")
    public void delete_table();

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    public void insertIntoTable(List<Table> tableList);
}
```

I am getting values from Rest call and then storing it on room DB

```
    public void addListOfTable(List<Table> tables) {
        
        dao.insertIntoTable(tables);

    }


    public void deleteTable() {
        
         dao.deleteTable();
           
    }
```

Please help me how to fix this issue.

I am using Room DataBase

Comment: can you show your entity ( model class )

Comment: @takieddine Please check the model class added in the question itself.

Comment: did you add your entitiy to the database class ?

Comment: please show the database and everything that has to do with saving your data , cause your room implementation seems all fine , or you can instead query by your enityt name , try  @Query("SELECT * FROM Table")

Comment: @takieddine I have added all the code needed for the database. Please check now.

Comment: i have submitted an answer for you below check it out

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that you re passing your room db class to your database instead of the entity itself , to fix that you need to do the following

`@Database(entities = {Table.class}, version = 2)  /// put Table.class instead`

Comment: sorry, I tried to mask the original table name. I forget to change there.

Comment: No. The issue still exists.

Comment: no such table: TableName (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM TableName

Comment: can you try and replace  TableName with Table , SELECT * FROM Table

Comment: I am able to insert values into DB. but the problem is after I performed delete operation and then tried to insert on that table means, then it was working one time, and another time it's throwing the above error.